# Regex - Search for consecutive elements from list without trailing and start whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of spoken numbers, and I want to search for consecutive members of this list in text.

So far I did:

```py
numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three']
N = re.compile(r'(({})\s){{1,10}}'.format('|'.join(numbers)))
```

Unofrtunately, when I have text: "one two three are my fav numbers" what I get is "one two three " with the trailing whitespace. Yet I cannot remove `\s` from my regex as numbers in text are separated with whitespaces.

How can I avoid matching starting and trailing space in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may refactor the regex as

```
N = re.compile(r'(?:{0})(?:\s(?:{0})){{0,9}}'.format('|'.join(numbers)))
```

The resulting regex will look like `(?:one|two|three)(?:\s(?:one|two|three)){0,9}` and will thus match one occurrence of the word number, and then 0 to 9 occurrences of a whitespace (use `\s+` to allow more than one whitespace between words), and then a word number.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HaEN8O):

```
import re
numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three']
N = re.compile(r'(?:{0})(?:\s(?:{0})){{0,9}}'.format('|'.join(numbers)))
text = "one two three are my fav numbers"
m = N.search(text)
if m:
  print ( '"{}"'.format(m.group()) ) # => "one two three"
```